# in the part assignment is not a symbol, create different matrices with a loop

Tags: matrix, symbols

Im trying to assemble new matrices from some previous matrices I have created, but I can´t. What Im trying to do is the following:

1) I have different matrices:

```
K11e[1] = {{a, a}, {a, a}};
K11e[2] = {{b, b}, {b, b}};
K12e[1] = {{aa, aa, aa, aa}, {aa, aa, aa, aa}};
K12e[2] = {{ab, ab, ab, ab}, {ab, ab, ab, ab}};
K22e[1] = {{ca, ca, ca, ca}, {ca, ca, ca, ca}, {ca, ca, ca, ca}, {ca, ca, ca, ca}};
K22e[2] = {{cb, cb, cb, cb}, {cb, cb, cb, cb}, {cb, cb, cb, cb}, {cb, cb, cb, cb}};
K21e[1] = {{da, da}, {da, da}, {da, da}, {da, da}};
K21e[2] = {{ba, ba}, {ba, ba}, {ba, ba}, {ba, ba}};
```

2) Define 2 vectors, I will used them to assemble my global matrices:

```
L1 = {1, 2};
L2 = {3, 4, 5, 6};
```

3) With "Do" assemble n matrices (2 for this example) with the previous matrices

```
Do[
KE[z] = ConstantArray[0, {6, 6}];
KE[z][[L1, L1]] = KE[z][[L1, L1]] + K11e[z];
KE[z][[L1, L2]] = KE[z][[L1, L2]] + K12e[z];
KE[z][[L2, L1]] = KE[z][[L2, L1]] + K21e[z];
KE[z][[L2, L2]] = KE[z][[L2, L2]] + K22e[z];, {z, 1, 2}]
```

4) So Im expecting to get this matrices:

```
KE[1] = {{a, a, aa, aa, aa, aa}, {a, a, aa, aa, aa, aa}, {da, da, ca, 
  ca, ca, ca}, {da, da, ca, ca, ca, ca}, {da, da, ca, ca, ca, 
  ca}, {da, da, ca, ca, ca, ca}};
KE[2] = {{b, b, ab, ab, ab, ab}, {b, b, ab, ab, ab, ab}, {ba, ba, cb, 
  cb, cb, cb}, {ba, ba, cb, cb, cb, cb}, {ba, ba, cb, cb, cb, 
  cb}, {ba, ba, cb, cb, cb, cb}}
```

But instead Mathematica give me the next error:

```
KE[z] in the part assignment is not a symbol.
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `ArrayFlatten` to build block matrices, for example

```
{{K11e[1], K12e[1]},
  {K21e[1], K22e[1]}} // ArrayFlatten
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also define your own function if you want to apply it to multiple cases

```
myFunc = ArrayFlatten@MapThread[List, {{K11e[#], K21e[#]}, {K12e[#], K22e[#]}}, 1] &

myFunc@1 // MatrixForm
```

> [image: Blockquote]